# Set env variables in a github action before deploying to firebase hosting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, github-actions, firebase-hosting

I have a React application that makes use of the automatic deploy Github actions that Firebase provides. My issue is that I don't push my `.env` file to Github, and therefore there are no environment variables built into my code when the workflow script file runs `yarn build` in the Github action.

I tried to get around this by setting variables on my Github settings for the repo. I tried both Github secrets (under "Actions") and "Environments".

For actions -> repository secrets, I set up a secret called `REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY` and added the following script to my `steps`:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=${{secrets.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}} yarn && yarn build
```

Then I also created an environment called `env`, and on actions -> environment secrets I added the same, and changed the script to:

```
REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY=${{env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}} yarn && yarn build
```

Neither of these worked; the env vars did not get bundled into the project and I get an error when I try to load maps on my live link because of a "missing api key".

How can I set secrets/variables in github and then utilise them in my workflow scripts?

For reference, here's the boilerplate script you get from firebase:

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
"on": pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: yarn && yarn build # I added my vars here, before `yarn` #
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_WEBPAGE_NAME }}"
          projectId: webpage_name
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define environment variables at three levels:

**Workflow:** available in the entire workflow.

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
on: pull_request
env:
  REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    ...
```

**Job:** available in all the steps of the job.

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
on: pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
    steps:
      ...
```

**Step:** available only in a specific step within a job.

```yaml
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on PR
on: pull_request
jobs:
  build_and_preview:
    if: "${{ github.event.pull_request.head.repo.full_name == github.repository }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: yarn && yarn build
        env:
          REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY }}
```

For your case, as you only need the API key during `yarn build`, declaring it in the step will be the best option.

Ref: https://docs.github.com/es/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

Comment: In your final code snippet you declare the `run` command **before** `env` - is that on purpose? Or should I declare my `env` variables first, then perform the `run` and prepend it with the env var, like I was in my question? Once I declare `env` does it automagically get injected into the build on `yarn build`, so I don't need to explicitly declare it like I would in my command line?

Comment: I guess the order doesn't really matter, but normally people place it after `run` (also in the docs). Once you declare it, the environment variable will be available in the scope of the step, so your `yarn build` will have access to it.